# Accessing Subclass variables Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

new to Objective-C/iOS and I can't figure out how to access a subclasses variable. So I've created a Person class which contains the following code:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property NSSTring *firstName;
```

and I've initiated this into the viewController and it all works fine.

next I right clicked on the Person class, and created a sub class of Person and added this:

```
#import "Person.h"

@interface Student : Person

@property NSInteger studentID;

@end
```

in the viewController;

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];

person.firstName = @"name";
person.lastName = @"lastname";
```

all works fine, but I can't figure out how to access the subclass Student's variable studentID?

I've tried initialising the subclass but it doesnt seem to work.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that from Person. You initialized a Person, not a Student. Subclasses can access parent properties, but not the other way around. You can do this:

```
Student *person = [[Student alloc] init];

person.firstName = @"name";
person.lastName = @"lastname";
person.sudentId = 123;
```

Comment: Think like that: Every Student is a Person BUT not every Person has to be a Student

Comment: okay cool thanks, that makes a little more sense. but how do I go about adding the data to studentID?

Comment: awesome thanks very much, so basically;

Every student is a person, but not every Person is a student;

so therefore, to add the Student's data, you have to initialise the Student class, which allows you to access the studentID, and from there subclasses can access parent classes which is how you add the rest of the data? (firstname and lastname)

Comment: okay great thanks, just one quick question. I've changed it so I'm initialising the Student class, but no matter what name I give either Student or the *person, it keeps coming up with an error saying "use of undeclared identifier Student?

Comment: Did you  `#import "Student.h"`?